# Which is more performant: 'replace' or 'substring'?

Tags: string, powershell, replace, substring

I frequently find that I can do what I need to do to a string using either `Substring` or `replace`.

For example: To get the remote GitHub URL of a local repo:

1. `(git remote get-url origin).replace('.git', '')`
2. ```
   $url = git remote get-url origin
   $url.substring(0, $url.indexof('.git'))
   ```

Obviously one is an extra line, but is it worth it?

Is there a technical reason to use one over the other, if any?

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately, in my opinion, its just as you said: "*personal preference*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course this is a preference.  It's also situational and you are best off trying to put tools in the tool box and trying to learn when it's best to use which.  And, I think that's in large part what your question is about.

With 2 working solutions, this particular example is the least of worries.  However, I'd point out that `.Replace()` case sensitive, as are many other underlying .Net string methods. `.Substring()` dealing with indices is not, but in your example you rely on .IndexOf()` which is case sensitive by default.

**Per mklement0's helpful comments:**

`.IndexOf()` & `LastIndexOf()` can be set to case insensitive using an additional overload like:

```
"SomEthing".IndexOf("e", [System.StringComparison]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Note: `.Replace()` in .Net 4.x and below doesn't have a case-insensitive mode and therefore no version of Windows PowerShell will have it either.  .Net core does have the option so it's available in PowerShell 6+.

For `.Replace()` and `.Split()` you're a little safer to use PowerShell native `-replace` & `-split`. Which are not only case insensitive by default, but also insulate you from potential changes in the .Net methods, as has in fact happened with `.Split()`'s overload preferences from .Net to .Net Core.

That said, and as examples of how to make such decisions the .Net methods are faster. So, situationally you might choose to use them over the PowerShell native operators. Just remain aware of caveats including but not limited to those discussed here.

Note: `.StartsWith()` & `.EndsWith()` are also case sensitive so we might instead check those conditions with `-match "^string"` or `-like "string*"`. Again these are just other examples of how you might decide between 2 different techniques.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, and I feel you've provided examples of how to make this decision objectively vs. subjectively.

Comment: I appreciate the feed back. Very rewarding to know I'm making an impact in the community.

Comment: Thanks for updating, Steven. Quick terminology note: .NET Framework is the Windows-only legacy edition of .NET, on which Windows PowerShell is built and on which it will remain. 4.8 is the latest and last ever version to be released. .NET Core was the name of the separate, cross-platform edition up to version 3.1. Starting with 5.0, the _Core_ part of the name was dropped, as was the case with PowerShell (Core) when v7 was released. Any .NET version starting with v5 therefore by definition refers to the cross-platform edition (as does any PowerShell version starting with v6).

Comment: To see what particular .NET version underlies a given PowerShell version, run `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::FrameworkDescription`.

Comment: OK I refined that update a little further.  Thanks for the info .Net 5 was throwing me. Was wondering why the Windows PowerShell requirements doc didn't mention it.  Note: that `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::FrameworkDescription` doesn't seem to work in 5.1.